# Get stats table from a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, eloquent, statistics, pivot-table

I have a pivot table for a Many to Many relationship between `users` and `collected_guitars`. As you can see a "collected_guitar" is an item that references some data in foreign tables (`guitar_models`, `finish`).

My users also have some foreign data in foreign tables (`hand_types` and `genders`)

I want to get a derived table that lists data if I look for a particular `model_id` in `"collected_guitar_user"`

Let's say "Fender Stratocaster" is model id = 200, where the make is Fender (id = 1 of makes table).
The same guitar could come in a variety of finish hence the use of another table `collected_guitars`.

One user could have this item in his collection

Now what I want to find by looking at model_id (in this case 200) in the pivot table "collected_guitar_user" is the number of Fender Stratocasters that are collected by users that share the same `genders.sex` and hand_types.type as the logged in user and to see what finish they divide in (some percent of finish A and B etc...).
So a user could see that is interested in what others are buying could see some statistics for the model.
What query can derive this kind of table??

[image]

Comment: By `collected_guitar` do you mean `owned_guitar`?

Comment: Do you have the Eloquent models, and relation scopes, already defined for these tables?

Comment: yes I do have all the models and relations defined.

Comment: Ok, I'm still kind of confused.  So for a given user (the currently authenticated user), you want to get a collection of other users who have the same gender and hand type.  Then, from that entire group of users, you want to find out how many Fender Stratocasters they own *in total*?  Or, how many Fender Stratocasters are owned by *each* of those users?

Comment: It works like this: the authenticated user submits a search for "fender stratocaster", the result should be all the fender stratocasters that are currently in the collections of other users that share the same hand and gender as the auth user. Let's say there is only one model named stratocaster, so the program will show that model along with the percent of each finish.. example solid 70%, transparent 30%.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106511/discussion-between-alexw-and-chriz74).

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregate counts by using the `GROUP BY` syntax, and `CROSS JOIN` to compute a percentage of the total:

```
SELECT make.make, models.model_name as model, finish.finish,
    COUNT(1) AS number_of_users,
    (COUNT(1) / u.total * 100) AS percent_owned
FROM owned_guitar, owned_guitar_users, users, models, make, finish
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS total FROM users) u
WHERE users.id = owned_guitar_users.user_id
AND owned_guitar_user.owned_guitar_id = owned_guitar.id
AND owned_guitar.model_id = models.id
AND owned_guitar.make_id = make.id
AND owned_guitar.finish_id = finish.id
GROUP BY owned_guitar.id
```

Please note though, that in cases where a user owns more than one guitar, the percentages will no longer necessarily sum to unity (for example, Jack and John could both own all five guitars, so each of them owns "100%" of the guitars).

I'm also a little confused by your database design.  Why do you have a `finish_id` and `make_id` associated directly in the `owned_guitar` table as well as in the `models` table?

Comment: this query returns empty result

Comment: Well it looks like you mispelled "finish" in your UML for the `owned_guitar` table.  Could that be part of the problem?  I don't have your entire database set up, so it's hard for me to test this query.

Comment: I'm also having trouble because your table names are inconsistent...some are pluralized (`users`, `models`) while others (`owned_guitar`) are not.  You might have to fix the names but otherwise this query should generally be the right approach.

Comment: sorry about that, I only made some example tables to show what I was looking for. Now I got something working. I also need to costrain the query to some users attributes that I didn't put in the example. For example find all the owned_guitars collected by users with same age